# Start a screen through svcadm with Solaris 11

Tags: solaris, gnu-screen, service

I am running into a problem when trying to start a detached screen through a Solaris 11 service.

This service controls nginx.  When I reboot the system, the screen doesn't start, but if I issue `svcadm disable nginx` then `svcadm enable nginx` manually, it does.  The rest of the init script functions correctly on a reboot (the nginx daemon starts, etc).

The part of the service that triggers the screen looks like this:

```
case "$1" in
    start)            
        echo "Starting Nginx Logger: \c"
        /usr/bin/screen -S nginxLogger -d -m /opt/php-5.3.10/bin/php $loggingProg
        LogRetVal=$?
        [ $LogRetVal -eq 0 ] & echo "ok" || echo "failed"
        ....
```

The log (/var/svc/log/network-nginx:default.log) shows that $LogRetVal is returning 0, and $loggingProg is just pointing to a PHP script.

If it matters, when I manually restart the service, I'm logged in as root.  I'm unsure how to check if it's a permission issue (I'm new to Solaris, I've recently switched from CentOS/RHEL).

Answer (score 0):

The most probably after restart it starts too early... may be sooner than networking is up. Put proper dependencies to service description XML.

Btw `svcs -xv` prints out services in maintenance state and its log file where you can find potential error.

And for what reason `screen`? It seems to be some misunderstandings of SMF.